# Maximum Flow in a Network

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

Let $N = (V, E)$ be a network in which the capacity of each edge is either $12$ or $18$.

**Prove or disprove:**
The value of a maximum flow for $N$ can’t be $56$.

I'm trying to figure out how to definitely prove this.
I think that this is not possible because of no combination of $12X + 18Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are integers) will ever $= 56$. Is there a better way of saying this? 
Am I right to say that an integer solution to $12X + 18Y = 56$ is what the Fold-Fulkerson algorithm implies?

Comment: Hint: can the minimum cut have a total capacity of 56?

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem

Comment: It looks like you have got the major ideas. I would encourage you to write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By the max flow min cut theorem, the maximum value of a flow equals the minimum capacity of a cut. The capacity of a cut is of the form 12x+18y, which can’t equal 56 because 56 is not a multiple of 6.